# error using the rankfeatures with the wilcoxon criterion in matlab

Tags: matlab

regarding the rankfeatures function in matlab how do we use correctly the wilcoxon criterion because i get this error:

**[IDX, Z] = rankfeatures(MFR, Group, 'wilcoxon', 0.005);**
??? Error using ==> rankfeatures at 151
Unknown parameter name: wilcoxon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> [IDX, Z] = rankfeatures(X, Group, ...'Criterion', CriterionValue, ...) sets the criterion used to assess the significance of every feature for separating two labeled groups.

This might not be obvious if you're not used to MATLAB functions, but when you see something like `'Criterion', CriterionValue` in the docs, this means that this function takes "name/value pairs" as input.

e.g. if using `plot`, and you want to set the type of marker used, you use the pair`'Marker','o'`, where `Marker` is the name, and `'o'` the value - you could use something else like `'x'` there but you have to give the name `'Marker'` first so the function knows what to do with the value `'o'`.

Similarly in this case to specify a criterion you need to write

`'Criterion','wilcoxon'` (or another applicable `CriterionValue`), not just `'wilcoxon'` by itself.

Comment: For the `0.005` it's the same issue, the parameter name is missing as well.